# PHP, No me puedo conectar a base de datos a pesar de tener los datos correctos

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

estoy intentando hacer una pagina web para subir datos a una tabla sql, me guie con un tutorial que vi en youtube y a pesar de tener todo bien escrito, me aparece el mensaje "Cannot POST /connect.php"

Adjunto mi  codigo PHP:

```php
<?php

    $id_estudiante = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id_alumno');
    $nombre_estudiante = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nombre_alumno');
    $apellido_estudiante = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'apellido_alumno');
    if(!empty($id)){
        $host = "localhost";
        $dbusername = "root";
        $dbpassword = "":
        $dbname = "mydb";

        //Aqui se crea la conexion

        $conn = new msqli($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);

        if(mysqli_connect_error()){
            die;
        }
        else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO estudiantes (id_estudiante, nombre_estudiante, apellido_estudiante)
                    values("$id_alumno", "$nombre_alumno", "$apellido_alumno")"
            if($conn->(query($sql))){
                echo "Alumno nuevo insertado";
            }
            else{
                echo "Error: ". $sql ."<br>". $conn->error; 
            }

        }

        $conn->close();
    }
    else{
        echo "Por favor, ponga un id";
        die;
    }
?>
```

En caso de que sea necesario, adjunto tambien mi codigo HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
      Revisar Dato
    </h1>

  </div>

  <li>
    <ul>
      <h3>
        Esta pagina esta diseñada para probar una funcion de revisar datos desde una base de datos

        Actualmente en ID se puede usar: 1, 2, 3
      </h3>
    </ul>
    <ul>
     <form action="/connect.php">
      ID Alumno: <input type="text" name="id_alumno"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
    </form> 
    </ul>
    <h3>
      La forma siguiente es para ingresar un alumno nuebo
    </h3>
    <ul>
     <form  method="post" action="connect.php">
      ID Alumno: <input type="text" name="id_alumno"><br>
      Nombre Alumno: <input type="text" name="nombre_alumno"><br>
      Apellido Alumno: <input type="text" name="apellido_alumno"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Subir">
    </form> 
    </ul>
  </li>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que el problema está en la conexión? Porque el fichero tiene unos cuantos errores (p.e. variable `$id` no definida, error de sintaxis en la consulta, punto y comas que faltan...) que deberían causar que el fichero falle de una manera u otra (aunque la conexión sea correcta). Haz que PHP te muestre los errores y comparte el error/stacktrace completo que recibes. Lee [ask] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio. Un saludo.

Comment: Estoy usando actualmente Sublime Text para escribir el codigo, ¿se pueden ver los errores desde ahi?

Comment: Pon esto al principio de tu fichero PHP: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` y eso te mostrará todos los errores y avisos. (no te olvides de quitarlo cuando termines!)

Comment: .o. !!!!
Muchas gracias! (sorry por las preguntas de novato, nunca he programado en php y aun asi me lo exigieron a ultima hora)

Comment: No te preocupes, todos hemos empezado alguna vez. Y en StackOverflow se aceptan preguntas de todos los niveles :)

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez podrías probar con esto:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
```

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "No se pudo conectar debido al siguiente error:" . mysqli_connect_error();
  }